# Vue won't render when mutating DOM

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, pinia

I am building a chat functionality in my app (using Typescript, Firebase and Pinia) where the user can create and join a room, where the messages are exchange.
The problem is that, after sending the message, the DOM won't update automatically, instead I have to reload the page. I tried using the ref in the store in the currentChatRoom and a watcher but it does nothing.

This is the chatStore:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'
import type { ITask, INewtask } from "../types/Task"
import {
    getFirestore, collection,
    addDoc, deleteDoc, doc,
    onSnapshot, query, where,
    orderBy, serverTimestamp,
    updateDoc,
    arrayUnion,
    getDocs,
    setDoc
} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { Fireapp } from '@/main'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import type { DocumentData } from '@firebase/firestore'

export default defineStore('chat-store', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            chatRoom: {
                createChatName: "",
                messages: [],
            },
            messageInput: "",
            joinChatName: "",
            currentChatRoom: ref(null as DocumentData | null)
        }
    },
    actions: {
        CreateChatRoom() {
            const db = getFirestore(Fireapp)
            const chatRoomCollection = collection(db, "chatRoom")
            const auth = getAuth()
            const user = auth.currentUser

            const newChatRoom = {
                createChatName: this.chatRoom.createChatName,
                messages: this.chatRoom.messages,
                users: []
            }


            if (user) {
                const userId = user.uid
                addDoc(chatRoomCollection, {
                    createChatName: this.chatRoom.createChatName,
                    messages: this.chatRoom.messages,
                    users: []
                })
                    .then((docRef) => {
                        console.log("Create a Room", docRef.id)
                        this.currentChatRoom = {
                            id: docRef.id,
                            createChatName: this.chatRoom.createChatName,
                            messages: this.chatRoom.messages,
                            users: []
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Error adding document: ", error)
                    })
            }
            this.currentChatRoom = newChatRoom

        },
        async JoinChatRoom(joinChatName: string): Promise<void> {
            if (!joinChatName) {
                console.error('Invalid chat room name:', joinChatName)
                return
            }

            const db = getFirestore(Fireapp)
            const chatRoomCollection = collection(db, 'chatRoom')

            try {
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
                    query(chatRoomCollection, where('createChatName', '==', joinChatName))
                )

                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                    console.log(`No such document with: ${joinChatName}`)
                    return
                }

                const doc = querySnapshot.docs[0]
                const chatRoomData = doc.data() as DocumentData
                console.log("joined Room", doc.id)

                this.currentChatRoom = {
                    id: doc.id,
                    createChatName: chatRoomData.createChatName,
                    messages: chatRoomData.messages || [],
                    users: chatRoomData.users || []
                }

                console.log('Chat room data:', this.currentChatRoom)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error joining chat room: ", error)
                throw error
            }
        },

        async SendMessage() {
            try {
                await this.JoinChatRoom(this.joinChatName)

                const db = getFirestore(Fireapp)
                const auth = getAuth()
                const user = ref(auth.currentUser)

                if (this.messageInput === "" || this.messageInput === null || !this.currentChatRoom) {
                    return
                }

                const chatRoomId = this.currentChatRoom ? this.currentChatRoom.id : null
                console.log("this is the data", chatRoomId)
                const newMessage = {
                    messages: this.messageInput,
                }

                const chatRoomDoc = doc(db, 'chatRoom', chatRoomId)
                await updateDoc(chatRoomDoc, {
                    messages: arrayUnion(newMessage),
                })


                console.log("Message sent")
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error sending message: ", error)
            }
        },

        ListenChanges() {
            const db = getFirestore(Fireapp)

            if (this.currentChatRoom && this.currentChatRoom.id) {
                const chatRoomDoc = doc(db, 'chatRoom', this.currentChatRoom.id)
                onSnapshot(chatRoomDoc, (doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists()) {
                        this.currentChatRoom = doc.data()
                        console.log(doc.data)
                    } else {
                        console.log("No document was found")
                        this.currentChatRoom = { id: null, createChatName: "", messages: [], users: [] }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
)
```

and this is the component when I try to display the messages:

````
<template>
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div> Chat </div>
        <div> {{ chatStore.chatRoom.createChatName }}</div>
        <div> {{ chatStore.joinChatName }}</div>
        <h4>Messages:</h4>
        <div
            v-for="(message, index) in messagesArr"
            :key="index"
        >{{ message.messages }}</div>
    </div>
    <form class="chat-input">
        <input
            type="text"
            v-model="chatStore.messageInput"
            name="messages"
            placeholder="write something..."
        >
        <button @click.prevent="chatStore.SendMessage()">Send</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import useChatStore from '@/stores/chat'
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'

const chatStore = useChatStore()

let messagesArr = chatStore.currentChatRoom.messages

watch(
    () => chatStore.currentChatRoom.messages,
    (newVal) => {
        messagesArr.value = newVal
    }
)
onMounted(() => {
    chatStore.ListenChanges()
})

</script>

<style>
.chat-input input {
    width: 100%;
}

.chat-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>```

Thank you already :)
````

Comment: Do you even need `watch()` for a Pinia store? Can't you access the store directly in your template rather than using `messagesArr`? In any case, `messagesArr` doesn't seem reactive at first glance. I'd expect to see `ref` or `reactive` used here? https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html

Comment: Should use [storeToRefs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Destructuring-from-a-Store) to reactively destructure `currentChatRoom` from `chatStore`, then it can be used directly in the template as `chatStore.messages`.  OR could just create a [getter](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html) that returns messages

Comment: Sorry for typo, I meant "directly in the template as `currentChatRoom.messages`"

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your messages with computed

```
const messagesArr = computed(()=>chatStore.currentChatRoom.messages)
```

If you mutate the messages you can do this instead

```
const messagesArr = computed({
   get: () => chatStore.currentChatRoom.messages,
   set: (v) => (chatStore.currentChatRoom.messages = v)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem.
I created a variable with an already reactive value, in this case chatStore.currentChatRoom.messages, which prevent its reactive functionality. Instead I had to iterate through that variable directly:

```
  <h4>Messages:</h4>
        <div
            v-for="(message, index) in chatStore.currentChatRoom?.messages"
            :key="index"
        >{{ message.messages }}</div>
    </div>
    <form class="chat-input">
        <input
            type="text"
            v-model="chatStore.messageInput"
            name="messages"
            placeholder="write something..."
        >
        <button @click.prevent="chatStore.SendMessage()">Send</button>
```